# Jetpack compose - Heterogenous list does not recompose on item click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, heterogeneous-list

I am creating Heterogenous list using Jetpack Compose. I have an issue with recomposition when one of the item is clicked. My idea is to update the list with new item when an item clicked, I am receiving update list but list is not recomposed.

Initial function that prepared screen where content of list is wrapped in Scaffold

```
@Composable fun PrepareOverViewScreen(overViewList: List<OverViewListItem>) {
    val infoList = remember {mutableStateOf(overViewList) }
    Scaffold(topBar = { TopBar("OverView") },
        content = { DisplayOverViewScreen(overViewList = overViewList) },
        backgroundColor = Color(0xFFf2f2f2)
    )


}
```

Displays list using LazyColumn when in itemType OverViewHeaderItem I am trying to recompose list with latest data , but not successful.

```
@Composable fun DisplayOverViewScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier, overViewList: List<OverViewListItem>
) {
    val infoList = remember {mutableStateOf(overViewList) }
    LazyColumn(modifier = modifier) {
        items(infoList.value) { data ->
            when (data) {
                is OverViewHeaderItem -> {
                    HeaderItem(data,infoList.value,onClick = { newValue ->
                        println("New Value is $newValue")
                        infoList.value = newValue.toMutableList()
                    })
                }
                is OverViewChildItem -> {
                    ChildListBasedOnListType(data)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this function the onClick is executed when clicked on Image()

```
@Composable fun HeaderItem(overViewHeaderItem: OverViewHeaderItem,overViewList: List<OverViewListItem>,onClick: (List<OverViewListItem>) -> Unit) {
    var angle by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0f)
    }
             Row(modifier = Modifier
                 .fillMaxWidth()
                 .height(50.dp)
                 .background(color = Color(0xffd7d7d7)),
                 horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start, verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                 Text(
                     text = stringResource(R.string.history_yesterday), color = Color.Black,
                     modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp)
                 )
             //    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
                 Image(
                     painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_expand_more),
                     modifier = Modifier
                         .padding(end = 5.dp)
                         .rotate(angle)
                         .clickable {
                             angle = (angle + 180) % 360f
                            // canDisplayChild = ! canDisplayChild
                             overViewList.map {
                                 when (it) {
                                     is OverViewChildItem -> {
                                         if (it.listType == ItemType.HISTORY_YESTERDAY_CHILD) {
                                             it.canShowHistoryChild = true
                                         }
                                     }
                                     else -> {}
                                 }
                             }
                           onClick(overViewList)
                         },
                     contentDescription = "Expandable Image"
                 )
             }


}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

```
@Composable fun ChildListBasedOnListType(overViewChildItem: OverViewChildItem){
       when(overViewChildItem.listType){
           ItemType.HISTORY_YESTERDAY_CHILD -> {
               if(overViewChildItem.canShowHistoryChild){
                   ChildListItem(overViewChildItem)
                   Divider(color = Color(0xffd7d7d7), thickness = 1.dp)
               }
           }
           else -> {
               ChildListItem(overViewChildItem)
               Divider(color = Color(0xffd7d7d7), thickness = 1.dp)
           }
       }
}

@Composable fun ChildListItem(overViewChildItem: OverViewChildItem) {
          ConstraintLayout(
            constraintSet = getConstraints(),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .height(60.dp)
                .background(color = Color(0xffffffff))
        ) {
            Text(
                text = overViewChildItem.article.articleName, Modifier
                    .layoutId("articleLabel")
                    .padding(start = 16.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight()
            )
            Text(
                text = overViewChildItem.article.description, Modifier
                    .layoutId("desc")
                    .padding(start = 16.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight()
            )

            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_chevron_right_24),
                modifier = Modifier.layoutId("detail"), contentDescription = "Detail Image"
            )
        }

}

@Composable fun getConstraints(): ConstraintSet {
    return ConstraintSet {
        val articleLabel = createRefFor("articleLabel")
        val articleDesc = createRefFor("desc")
        val detailImage = createRefFor("detail")
        createVerticalChain(articleLabel, articleDesc, chainStyle = ChainStyle.Packed)
        constrain(articleLabel) {
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
            start.linkTo(parent.start)
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
        }
        constrain(articleDesc) {
            top.linkTo(articleLabel.bottom)
            start.linkTo(parent.start)
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
        }
        constrain(detailImage){
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
            end.linkTo(parent.end,5.dp)
            bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
        }
    }
}
```